# See the full POST from Twilio Studio http request widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm using the Twilio Studio to build an SMS flow and trying to post the results to a database.

I'm getting an error from the post, but I can't seem to find what is being sent by the HTTP Request widget, I only see the results. I'm hoping if I can find the full POST syntax germinated I'll find my issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the widget to POST to https://requestb.in/? That should show you what is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following information in the *Engagement Log* under "logs".

- URL called
- Method
- Request Body
- Response code
- Response content-type

But sadly, not any other headers.